# How to speed up response of Google Speech to Text api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text

```
    def transcribe_gcs_v2(
            self,
            gcs_uri: str,
            language: str
    ) -> cloud_speech.RecognizeResponse:

        client = SpeechClient()

        config = cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig(
            auto_decoding_config=cloud_speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
            language_codes=[language],
            model="long",
        )

        request = cloud_speech.RecognizeRequest(
            recognizer=f"projects/{self.project_id}/locations/global/recognizers/_",
            config=config,
            uri=gcs_uri,
        )

        response = client.recognize(request=request)

        transcript_result = []
        for result in response.results:
            transcript_result.append(result.alternatives[0].transcript)

        transcript_result = "".join(transcript_result)
  
        return transcript_result
```

My process goes like this: I first pass the file to the gcs bucket and then get the gcs url,Use this url to call the api.

When I send a 20-second voice message to the api, it usually takes about 10 seconds to translate，It's been too long.

How to reduce the translation time, I hope to reach 2-3 seconds.